# How to have different anchor faces for Source and Target in JSPlumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

Here is my use case:

[image]

I want to be able to set **Continuous** anchor faces separately for **Source** and **Target** in a JSPlumb Connection.

**For source**: Continuous anchors on the '**right**'

**For target**: Continuous anchors on the '**left**'

I have tried setting the continuous anchors separately but it doesn't seem to work.

The documentation isn't clear enough on this.

I have tried this:

```
 jsPlumb.connect( {
      .......
      anchor : ["Continuous", { faces:["right"] } ]
      ..... 
 });
```

But, how do I specify different anchor faces for taget and source?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

`jsPlumb.connect({
  source:someDiv,
  target:someOtherDiv,
  anchors:["Bottom", "Continuous"]
});`.

Mind that it is **anchors** not **anchor** when specifying where to be placed.
I've tried using `anchors:[["Right"], ["Left"], "Continuous"]` and it seems to work but since my scenario is different than yours I cannot be sure if it is what you need.